# A walk with mom.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

A mother takes two strides to her daughter's three. If they set out walking together, each starting with the right foot, when will they first step together with the left?

Is there a general solution to these type of questions?

*ps I have no idea how to tag this question*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  Let the timestep be $\frac 12$ the time of the daughter's stride, which is $\frac 13$ the time of the mother's stride.  If they both stride right at time $0$, the daughter strides left at time $2$ and the mother at time $3$.  Keep going with the pattern.  If you get back to both striding right you have found a complete cycle.